# how to convert php date format according to mysql date format?

Tags: php

I have a form that saves a date into a mysql database. Before the date is saved I need to convert the format. How can this be done more elegantly than the code I have below? I know it can but not sure how to do it correctly.

```
//Get the date (22/03/2018)
     $start=$_POST['start']; 

//Remove the /and replace with -
    $starttime = str_replace('/', '-', $start);

convert the format to y-m-d
    $starttime=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($starttime));
```

Answer (score 1):

User strtotime on the date string and format it as you want:

```
$datestring = $_POST['start'];
$dateval = strtotime($datestring );
$start = date('Y-m-d', $dateval );
```

Or an other code:

```
$datestring = $_POST['start'];
$dateval = new DateTime(datestring);
$start  = $dateval->format('Y-m-d');
```

Is it the correct date form? You can read some info here: [php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
One part from a note: "...if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed..." 
So this may cause a problem.

If the day, month, year parts are fix you can use "#Rahul Shrivastava" 's comment as well.

Comment: it will not give the expected output

Comment: Which one not give back the date correctly? The Europian and the American date format are different and as I read it could cause problem.

Answer (score 1):

## The best way

is using the class **DateTime** is: http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['start']);
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

It's a minimal library that makes date really flexible, you can install via composer typing `composer require nesbot/carbon`

Which will enable you to do something like

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->toDateTimeString();
// Returns something like 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```

From there you can do pretty much whatever you want with it!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (the simplest one):

```
$starttime = preg_replace('/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/', "$3-$2-$1", $_POST['start']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try `list()` with `preg_split()`

```
$start=$_POST['start'];
//Get the date (22/03/2018)       
list($day,$month,$year) = preg_split('/[\/\s:]+/', $start); 
    echo $date = $year . '-' . $month. '-' .  $day ;
```